# SparkContext stopped yet application runs in yarn cluster mode

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

I have written a spark batch job and called stop() method on the spark context as soon as I have completed the execution of the batch. Then I executed this batch in Yarn (AWS) in cluster mode. It runs fine but the application does not end on its own. I have to explicitly kill it from the YARN UI. I think that the sparkContext.stop() has been called and the context has been ended, but the application did not end. This is the code that I tried to execute -

```
JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(sparkConf);
sc.newAPIHadoopRDD(inputConfiguration, TableInputFormat.class, ImmutableBytesWritable.class, Result.class)
            .mapToPair(t -> {
                HbaseEntity entity = new HbaseEntity(t._2(), toTableName, columnFamily);
                return new Tuple2<>(entity.getKey(), entity);
            })
            .reduceByKey(hbaseEntityReducer)
            .mapToPair(t -> t._2().createPutTuple())
            .saveAsHadoopDataset(outJobConf);

sc.stop();
```

Spark application submit command used -

```
spark-submit --master yarn-cluster --class com.self.spark.SparkBatch spark-batch.jar
```

I cannot understand why the YARN application does not end or finish. Can anyone help me with this? Also tell me how to go about it so that the application ends as soon as the stop() method is executed.